# delay() vs delayMicroseconds()

Tags: arduino-nano

I just started using Arduino and so far I've used both `delay()` and `delayMicroseconds()`. I was wondering what the difference between these two is, because it seems to me that they're the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/delay):

> ## delay()
>
> ### Description
>
> Pauses the program for the amount of time (in miliseconds) specified as parameter. (There are 1000 milliseconds in a second.)

So... milliseconds vs. microseconds.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I missed that.